# Storing information into the order and order_details table in one go

Tags: laravel, eloquent, store, relation, belongs-to

So hear me out. If I place an **order**, I would like to **store** the order and the actual order details. One table to store the orderID, productID, order_status and is_delivered whereas the other table contains of the delivery address, price and quantity.

I have setup the **relations** and everything, but one thing that I am trying to figure out is:

How do I retrieve the orderID from the order so I can insert it into the order_details table as my foreign key in one go? Is there any chance that this is possible?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have one to many relation between `order` and `order_details`

```
$order = Order::create($orderData);
$orderDetails = [
    [$orderDetailsArray_1],
    [$orderDetailsArray_2],
];

$order->order_details->createMany($orderDetails);
```

This will save relational data on thy fly.
See the [DOC](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) to learn more.